# How can I compute the Big-O notation for a given piece of code?

Tags: performance, complexity

So I just took a data structure midterm today and I was asked to determine the run time, in Big O notation, of the following nested loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++2) {
        //1 Statement
    }
}
```

I'm having trouble understanding the formula behind determining the run time. I thought that since the inner loop has 1 statement, and using the series equation of:
(n * (n - 1)) / 2, I figured it to be: 1n * (n-1) / 2. Thus equaling (n^2 - 1) / 2.
And so I generalized the runtime to be O(n^2 / 2). I'm not sure this is right though haha, was I supposed to divide my answer again by 2 since j is being upped in intervals of 2?
Or is my answer completely off?

Comment: Was that a `j++2` or a ` j+=2`?

Comment: When it comes to big `O` notation, you do not need to divide your answer by anything: all you need to do is to keep the highest power, and throw away everything else. The answer to this one is `O(n^2)`

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: can you clarify why this is (n^2)?  It is a nested loop, but it seems that j is a constant, therefore, it would not be squared, but rather O(n).  (not very familiar with this notation, so an explanation would be great).

Comment: `j` is not a constant. As `n` increases the inner loop takes proportionally more time.

Comment: @gahooa But `j` is not a constant, it goes from zero to `i` with each iteration of the outer loop, bringing the result to `O(n^2)`

Comment: Oh, my bad.  Thanks!  I didn't see the `i` incrementing in the outer loop.

Comment: Belongs on the theoretical computer science forum.

Comment: I think [this question @SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it) with 60k views provides with relevant information.

Answer (score 2):

To be precise, `//1 statement` would matter a lot in calculating the Big-O notation for a given piece of code. But considering that it takes a constant time ( I am supposing it is a count+=1 statement) then your solution would go like:

```
(Sigma i (over 1 to n) (Sigma j (over 1 to i))
```

And this would lead to O(n^2).

I suggest that you solve the problems at this [link](http://www2.algorithm.cs.sunysb.edu:8080/mediawiki/index.php/Algo-analysis-TADM2E) once. These will give you a good idea.